# Erro apache = get overlap result error

Tags: apache

Estou com um erro do apache que não consigo corrigir, no log do php nenhum erro é reportado somente no apache.

Alguém ja identificou algo assim?
Abaixo o log do apache:

> [Mon Jan 05 10:20:26 2015] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 109)O pipe
> foi finalizado. : mod_fcgid: get overlap result error
>
> [Thu Jan 15
> 16:51:06 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script
> headers: processarNotas.php

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.32 (Windows 7 Business Edition) i586 o mesmo erro para o Linux onde é o servidor de produção.

Comment: Por incrível que pareça as vezes este erro não é por má configuração no apache, as vezes é devido algum problema com script ou extensão php. No caso como no teu Linux e Windows ocorrem o mesmo problema provavelmente é um problema no teu script. Portanto poste o script que ocasiona o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se adicionar isso no seu `vhosts.conf` resolve seu problema:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  # 5 minutes for IO timeout, default is 40 seconds
  FcgidIOTimeout 300
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Na verdade eu ja tinha configurado direto no httpd.conf com FcgidIOTimeout  3600; Mas tentei a sua sugestão e o mesmo erro ocorreu.